# Are these Categories Equivalent?

Tags: category-theory

I've got a question about the following two categories:
\begin{align*} x_0 \rightarrow y \leftarrow x_1, && 0 \rightarrow 1, \end{align*}
the first called $ D $ and the second called $ 2 $. Then there is a unique functor $ F : D \Rightarrow 2 $ mapping objects as below,
\begin{align*}
    F : D &\to 2 \\\\ 
        x_0 &\mapsto 0 \\\\ 
        x_1 &\mapsto 0 \\\\
        y &\mapsto 1 .
\end{align*}
Now $ F $ seems to be

- full,
- faithful, and
- (essentially) surjective.

Hence $ F $ defines an equivalence of categories.

But $ D $ and $ 2 $ are equivalent iff $ \mathrm{sk}(D) \cong \mathrm{sk}(2) $, i.e. the two skeletons are isomorphic. But $ D = \mathrm{sk}(D) $ and $ 2 = \mathrm{sk}(2) $ and no such isomorphism exists... right? So what's going on? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\hom(x_0, x_1) \to \hom(0, 0)$ isn't surjective, so $F$ isn't full.

Comment: Thank you, I'm an idiot... do you delete dumb questions or leave them up?

Comment: That's up to you: delete the question if you don't think it has any ongoing value to MSE readers.